# Why I can't install any package using pip and pip3 but python3 -m?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, homebrew

What I am trying to do is that simply installing a Python package using `pip`. But the followings does not work as expected:

```
$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.7.4.post0)

$ pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.7.4.post0)
```

```
$ python main.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

$ python3 main.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

But the following command fixes the issue:

```
$ python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Versions:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.16

$ python3 -V
Python 3.9.7

$ pip -V
pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ pip3 -V
pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

OS: `macOS 11 Intel`

Both Python and Python3 installed via `brew`.

What's wrong with my Python environment?

Comment: pip refers to a 3.8 installation while "python" and "...3" refer to other versions and therefore other installations.

Comment: You have probably also both `pip3.8` and `pip3.9` If you want to have both Python versions, use explicit `pip3.x` or `python3.x`. If you want to have only the most recent version, uninstall the 3.8 and check the symlinks in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the pip 3 pointing to other version of python `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-package`
while python3 refers to `Python 3.9.7`
The best option is to use python3 -m pip to run pip with a specific python version.